# Azure DevOps link work items to commit message as mandatory

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to create a rule in Azure DevOps which enforces linking work items to azure repo commit as mandatory?

Comment: I am afraid there is no such a feature in azure devops currently. You can consider setting up the branch policy answered by Max in below  as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enforce linking work items for individual commits. However, you can require that work items be linked as part of your Pull Request Policy.

Here's Microsoft's documentation on how to set it up:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#check-for-linked-work-items